# UIWebView keeps zooming on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, ios5

I have a older app where in a UIWebView I loaded a movie from a URL. It worked just fine. But now on iOS 5 ... when I enter the ViewController containing the UIWebView ... the thumbnail of the video starts "growing" like someone would zoom on it and it doesn't stop.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.link_go_here"]];     

[infoWebView loadRequest:request];
```

(it's a universal app ... the same happens on both devices)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the `infoWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;` property of the webview? You could also try to set

```
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0'/>
```

of the html page your loading.

Comment: i tried to put the scalesPageToFir property to NO ... still the same behaviour ... and I'm now looking into the source code for the page

Comment: Okay, theres alos this meta: <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />

Comment: tried them .. didn't work ... also i tried to add them from java script (seen somewhere on internet) since I didn't make the webpage I was loading the video from.

Comment: Thank you anyway, talking to my client to give me the video as a resource.